# Asynchronous AddThis call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, addthis

I have a Razor partial view that loads through AJAX as soon the user clicks the button. In the view HTML I have the following AddThis markup:

```
<div class="addthis_native_toolbox" data-url="@sale.Url" data-title="@sale.Name"></div>
```

The same code is being used when rendering the existing items on the page, without AJAX, so I assume the problem is not related with incorrect reference or usage of AddThis.

Additionaly, I use this piece of jQuery to reinitialize AddThis buttons:

```
$.get("/umbraco/surface/Calendar/LoadMoreSales?months=" + months, function (data) {
            if (data != '') {
                $("#saleList").append(data);
            }
            else {
                months = -1;
                $("#saleList").append('No more news to display');
            }

            _inCallback = false;
            $('div#loading').empty();
        })
          .success(function () {
            addthis.init();
});
```

Also, I have added the `async` attribute to .js library reference:

```
Html.RequiresJs("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=<PUD_ID_KEY>&async=1");
```

I have followed all the instructions stated on [AddThis website](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1293805-using-addthis-asynchronously), but the markup is still not transforming.

Anyone can notice what I am missing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I was using the wrong documentation reference.

Here is the new one with proper initialize code: [link to AddThis documentation](http://www.addthis.com/academy/using-dashboard-configuration-tools-dynamically/).

This was the code I needed in the place of `addthis.init();`: `addthis.layers.refresh();`.